# Parent window handles the Keyup event from the child window in WPF

Tags: wpf

A parent window is designed having keyup event attached.
The MainWindow goes like:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e != null && e.Key == Key.Return)
        {
            MessageWindow msgWindow = new MessageWindow("KEY UP");
            msgWindow.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

The MessageWindow having a button OK to close the window, goes like:

```
public partial class MessageWindow : Window
{

    public MessageWindow()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MessageWindow(string message) : this()
    {
        txtMess.Text = message;
    }

    private void btnOk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

On receiving the input key as [Return] on parent, a new child window is initialized and is displayed.
Press TAB to focus OK button and press Enter.
The child MessageWindow pops up again.

Reason: Parent window receives KeyUp event when RETURN key is pressed on child window to close it.

Please provide a way to stop the handling of KeyUp event by parent, other than using a FLAG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use PreviewKeyDown event instead of KeyUp one

Comment: This answer is correct, but I wanted to add that this is because the PreviewX events tunnel from the root element down to the most nested element, whereas normal X events bubble from the most nested element up to the root element.

This means that the root element gets the first opportunity to handle a tunnelled event and the last opportunity to handle a bubbled event.